# How to achieve completion in tmux statusline

Tags: tmux

Is there any way to achieve tab completion in tmux's status line. Let me give a use-case:

```
bind-key v command-prompt "split-window -h 'exec vim %%'"
```

This is from my tmux.conf. It will be a great idea if only I could get paths to complete in the tmux statusline. I've looked around but did not find anything. Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks.